# javascript -Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined

Tags: javascript, json

```
function Userinfo (ad,age,city,street){
    this.ad = ad
    this.age = age
    this.city = city
    this.street = street
}

let orxan = new Userinfo ('Orxan',30,'sumqayit','sulh')

console.log(orxan[age])
```

why console.log(orxan[age] is not working but console.log(orxan.age) working

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+bracket+notation+referenceerror) of [Why am I getting a ReferenceError: 'x' is not defined?](/q/45410307/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

You must enclose age in quotes like so:

```
console.log(orxan['age'])
```

Otherwise Javascript will search for variable named `age` in the scope

Full snippet:

```
function Userinfo (ad,age,city,street){
    this.ad = ad
    this.age = age
    this.city = city
    this.street = street
}

let orxan = new Userinfo ('Orxan',30,'sumqayit','sulh')

console.log(orxan['age'])
```

Results in:

```
$node main.js
30
```